# How to append a dynamic string to the end of a copy's filename

Tags: unix, sed, awk

Conside File is :

```
/home/dev/a1234.txt
```

I want to copy this file in /home/sys/  directory but I want to add some number on the file name while copying. 
Date1=`date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S`
Output should be :

```
/home/sys/a1234.txt.$Date1
```

Number on the filename "1234" will be different everytime. so File name is not fixed.

Please suggest.

Comment: File name is dynamic and the number I want to add is the current date. so it also will be changing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you on the way:

```
for i in $( ls /home/dev | grep 'a[0-9]*.txt$'); do
    cp /home/dev/$i /home/sys/$i.`date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S`;
done
```

You can improve it by seeing if the file has already been copied, and prevent it from being copied a second time.

Comment: I think it's probably safer/faster if you use something like `for i in /home/dev/*.txt` instead of the `ls`-`grep` combination; also might be a good idea to quote the arguments of `cp` in case of whitespace and other special characters in filenames.

Comment: @doubleDown sure, nice suggestions, OP can take them on board.

Answer (score 0):

In two steps:

- Copy the file to `/home/sys`.

  ```
  cp /home/dev/a1234.txt /home/sys
  ```
- Move from `a1234.txt` to `a1234.txt.130625`. This way you can make it more general.

  ```
  mv /home/sys/a1234.txt{,$date} #is expanded to mv /home/sys/a1234.txt /home/sys/a1234.$date
  ```

As you indicate your file name will change, you can generalise my answer with `$file_name` instead of `a1234.txt`.

#### Test

```
$ touch a
$ date=23
$ mv aa{,$date}
$ ls
aa23
```

Comment: what is the source and what is the destination here ? move command will require two parameters

Comment: No, this way `mv` does not need a destination. See my updated answer

Comment: This will work but when I know the exact file name. In my case I dont know the file name, I know the static part of the file name is only a, so I have to copy the file like cp /home/dev/a* /home/sys. So as per ur next step , I cant use mv /home/sys/a1234.txt{,$date} ,File will be different everytime , I dont know the name of the file. Now Can you please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
NAME=a1234.txt
cp dev/$NAME sys/$NAME.$Date1
```

Comment: Name will be changing everytime. So I cant store it in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date` command to get the current date.

```
$ DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S`; NAME=a; EXT=txt; for i in {0..4}; do echo $NAME$i$.$EXT.$DATE; done
a0.txt.20130625
a1.txt.20130625
a2.txt.20130625
a3.txt.20130625
a4.txt.20130625
```

Change the `echo` line to be a `cp`:

```
$ DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S`; FROMDIR=/home/dev; TODIR=/home/sys; NAME=a; EXT=txt; for i in {0..4}; do cp $FROMDIR/$NAME$i.$EXT $TODIR/$NAME$i$.$EXT.$DATE; done
```

---

This is probably better in a bash script where you can modify it easier than a single liner:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get current date
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S`;

# specify from directory and to directory for cp
FROMDIR=/home/dev;
TODIR=/home/sys;

# set base filename and extension
NAME=a;
EXT=txt;

# count from 0 to 4
for i in {0..4}; do
    # copy file and add date to end of new filename
    cp $FROMDIR/$NAME$i.$EXT $TODIR/$NAME$i$.$EXT.$DATE;
done
```

`i` increments from `0` to `4` in this example, while a filename of the form `$NAME$i.$EXT` is copied from `$FROMDIR` to `TODIR` -- with the current date in `$DATE` appended to the end of the copy's filename.